# Mac OS X Terminal Bash change directory issue

Tags: macos, bash

I am running Mac OS X and I have the latest Parallels installed. However, after installing Parallels, it added a directory called Applications (parallels).

So now if I start my terminal, I would see both Applications and Applications (parallels). Now the issue is I can't seem to get into my Mac's Applications directory anymore.

Every time I type cd applications, it would go into the parallels one. I don't know how to get back to my normal Mac's application.

If anyone has some advice, please do let me know.

```
Applications        Library
Applications (Parallels)    Movies
Desktop             Music
Documents           Pictures
Downloads           Public
Dropbox
```

and after I type cd Applications and ls, I get this:

```
Windows 8 Release Preview (English) Applications.app
Ricks-MacBook-Pro:Applications rickel$
```

Comment: I tried all possiblies, Applications, and applications both goes into parallels one...and yes i use ls to list the directory

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us that output. Don't forget to select the text and press `Ctrl-K` in the editor so it's aligned properly.

Comment: edits have been made.

Comment: Does this only happen in Terminal? What about in Finder?

Comment: I actually meant `ls -la`, not `ls` alone, but I understand now what the "problem" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After typing `cd Applications`, you'll land in `/Users/rickel/Applications` in your home directory, because the shell usually starts in `/Users/rickel`. This is indicated by the prompt, actually:

```
Ricks-MacBook-Pro:Applications rickel$
```

The folder name is `Applications` here, not `Applications (Parallels)`. Don't be fooled by the Windows 8 app there.

Do note that this folder is empty on OS X, by default. Your standard applications are still there, but they are always installed to `/Applications` in the root directory. To get there, type:

```
cd /Applications
```

The Parallels folder is added in your home directory again. You do not get there unless you type the following (note the quotes needed because there are spaces inside the name):

```
cd 'Applications (Parallels)'
```

Comment: thx, so i had to do cd applications twice to get into where I want.  You mentioned that i need to capitalize the A but I didn't and it still works for me.  What is the reason it works for me?

Comment: Interesting – I didn't know `cd`ing was case insensitive by default. Sorry about that, it appears that always works. In any case, if you type `cd applications` twice in a row, you get to your `/Applications` folder?

Comment: I am guessing in a raw linux/unix environment, it would be case sensitive but in mac osx, it has probably been modified for user friendliness...